# If I want to build an Android app that supports Android 2.2, do I need to install the SDK for 2.2 or is everything I need in the 4.42 SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, api

As the title says. Will I be missing things if I don't install SDK for 2.2(API 8) ?

Comment: What do you mean by install API 8? You mean in the SDK manager? If yes then the newest API is all you need.

Comment: Apologies, yes, you are correct, I mean in the SDK manager, I'll correct it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need will be in the 4.42 SDK, however be aware that there will be features of the 4.42 SDK that won't be supported on Android 2.2 since the SDK is far newer than the target version of Android. This won't cause any problems however, as long as you don't try to implement any of the unsupported features.